# How to add route to a controller in custom directory?

Tags: php, routes, symfony

In Symfony 3 I am trying to load routing from controllers which are not in a bundle using a directory path, but parameter `%kernel.root_dir%` is not resolved here. It works if I use absolute path.

**My routing.yml file:**

```
mymodule:
    resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyModule/Controller'
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /mymodule
```

Do you have any suggestion how to use relative path without referencing a bundle?

Comment: Take a look here: http://elnur.pro/symfony-without-bundles/ It may help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a path relative to the current config file:

`resource: ../../src/MyModule/Controller`